# Script for compiling C++

Tags: bash, compilation, g++

I want to make a script that would make compiling things quicker to write. I want to compile a XYZ.cpp file and the I want the output to be XYZ.out.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# getting the part before .cpp
var1=`echo "$1" | cut -d"." -f1`

# compile
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long "$1" -o "$var1.out" -lm
```

I run it: `ccc program.cpp`

The script runs but the output still is `a.out`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you echo the value of `$var1`, what is it?

Comment: Run the script with `xtrace` on, for example:  `bash -x ccc program.cpp`.  That will show all the expansions and clarify what is happening..

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of [bash's built-in parameter expansion features](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove any trailing portion of `$1` that matches ".cpp":

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -o "${1%%.cpp}.out" -lm "$1"
```

I've also moved the source file to be the last parameter to g++, so that it's clear where the options are (and end).